# Many-Many and One-Many on same collection Entity Framework 6 with InverseProeprty

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have the following:

```
public class Event : IEntity
{
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    [JsonProperty("id")]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("description")]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("date")]
    public DateTimeOffset Date { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("distance")]
    public int Distance { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("verticalAscend")]
    public int VerticalAscend { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("User")]
    [JsonProperty("userId")]
    public Guid UserId { get; set; }

    //attending
    public DateTimeOffset DateCreated { get; set; }
    public DateTimeOffset DateModified { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("user")]
    public virtual User User { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("comments")]
    public virtual ICollection<Comment> Comments { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("attending")]
    public virtual ICollection<User> AttendingList { get; set; }
}
```

And:

```
public class User : IEntity
{
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    [JsonProperty("id")]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("profilePicUrl")]
    public string ProfilePicUrl { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("surname")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("email")]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    public DateTimeOffset DateCreated { get; set; }
    public DateTimeOffset DateModified { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Event> AttendingEvents { get; set; }
    [InverseProperty("User")]
    public virtual ICollection<Event> Events { get; set; }
}
```

Relationships:

Event:

- Many Users attending (AttendingList)

User:

- Can attend many events (AttendingEvents)
- Can create multiple events (Events)

There exists a many-many relationship between the Event.AttendingList and User.AttendingEvents.
There exists 0-many relationship between Event.User and User.Events, with ForeignKey as UserId.

I am trying to configure these with Fluent API, and using the `InverseProperty` to configure the other side of the relationship, mapping back to `Event.User`, but getting the following error:

> Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_dbo.UserEvents_dbo.Events_Event_Id' on table 'UserEvents' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.

I am unsure on how to solve this relationship on one table.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I do not have a class for that.  Not sure where this comes from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `DbContext` configure your models as follows:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
     base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

     modelBuilder.Entity<Event>().HasRequired(e => e.User)
            .WithMany(u => u.Events)
            .HasForeignKey(e => e.UserId)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

     modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
            .HasMany<Event>(s => s.AttendingEvents)
            .WithMany(c => c.AttendingList)
            .Map(cs =>
            {
                cs.MapLeftKey("UserId");
                cs.MapRightKey("EventId");
                cs.ToTable("UserEvents");
            });
}
```

Comment: This does not quite work right.  Now the event table has three User id fields, namely UserId, User_Id and User_Id1.  Also, the UserEvents table is not created

Comment: What? Surely you are missing something! I have generated everything cleanly in my side with this code.

Comment: Did you remove the InverseProperty in my User class?  I am double checking quick to make sure everything matches

Comment: Are you talking about this: `[InverseProperty("User")]
    public virtual ICollection<Event> Events { get; set; }`

Comment: Yes.  I removed those, but still I do not get the result you get.  Not sure what needs to change my side.  Still investigating

Comment: No did not remove this. Come to chat please!

Comment: Hmmm... I got your answer to work, by placing the fluent api code in the "OnModelCreating()", and removing it out of my "EntityTypeConfiguration<Event>" class....

Comment: Yep.  Accepted it

Comment: Great! Thank you so much!

Comment: You said that it was not working from `EntityTypeConfiguration<Event>` class but I got it working. Here is my EventConfiguration: https://imgur.com/dZyaKMr

Comment: Note: Delete the existing database and migrations. Generate it from initial migration. From existing migration it did not work for  me too.

Comment: What do you mean 'from initial migration'?  My process is as follow: Delete Migration folder. Run: Enable-Migrations -> Add-Migration Initial -> Update-Database

Comment: What do you mean 'from initial migration'? `Delete Migration folder and database too. Run: Enable-Migrations -> Add-Migration Initial -> Update-Database`